# Can you search for code in google?

Tags: google, google-search, search

can you search for code in google ? not just git hub ect but i mean live code so instead of searching by site content, search by sites source code ? (obviously only client side code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - while Google may keep source code in its indexes, it does not provide a facility for searching sites' markup.

Comment: Though it should be noted that Google *did* offer a labs product called [Google Code Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code_Search), for searching open source code - which is probably where this idea comes from.